# Can "dare" be followed by a present continuous tense?

Tags: modal-verbs

I want to know if the following sentence is correct :

"How dare you are not drinking tonight?"

Comment: Firstly, this is an [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)-level question. Secondly, it would be Off Topic "proofreading" even there unless edited to show some *specific cause of concern in the text*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can, as long as the continuous form is in infinitive:

> How dare you not *be drinking* tonight!

Your original sentence is not grammatical

Comment: Yes. One could say that. But it is not an infinitive. That would be *to drink*.

Comment: @WS2: Nah - Armen's usage is okay here. *The [continuous infinitive](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/continuous-infinitive/) is used to express a continuing action after **a verb or auxiliary** which must be **followed by the infinitive.***

Comment: @WS2: *to drink*, *to have drunk*, *to be drinking* - all of these are infinitive, since they do not have *person*, *number*, *tense* etc. They do have some sort of *aspect* though.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան My apologies. I stand corrected. I suffer the disadvantage of being a native speaker, knowing instinctively what is correct grammar, but without being able to explain why!+1.